# Will this driver circuitry work as intended to switch half-bridge FETs?

Tags: power-electronics, ground, driver

[image: DC/DC isolator and high side gate driver]

Given that the PWM_H signal is referenced to SGND and the driver is referenced to VSW (switch node of the half bridge), will the gate driver function correctly without a connection between the driver's GND and the external SGND?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

The IC you use is a low-side driver which has its inputs and output referenced to its GND pin. So if you apply `PWM_H` signal to its input the signal should be referenced to the IC's GND pin. `VEEH` and `SGND` appear to be isolated so no, this won't work.

What you should do is to "translate" your `SGND` to your `VSW` node. This can be done using optocouplers or gate-drive transformers<sup>**1**</sup>:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpsTmm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*NOTE: Above is a simplified diagram so it doesn't show all details. I also have shown your IC as a push-pull driver in the schematic above, just for simplicity, although even a push/pull driver would work.*

Another option is to use a dedicated high-side driver (usually bootstrap) or a hi- and low-side combined driver which employs a bootstrap driver for high-side and does the SGND-VS translation for you.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> If you use a gate-drive transformer you actually don't need any isolated power rail.